# Why am I entering a loop?

Tags: java, loops

It works fine and gives me the correct output until it enters the last object to add to `nonEmptyList` in the `sample()` method. I have managed to find out where it is looping, which is in the while loop in the `add(item)` method. I can't change the methods or returns, so if anyone could suggest a way I could prevent this infinite loop, that would be appreciated.

```
public class SampleableListImpl implements SampleableList {

    public int size;
    public Object firstLink = null; //Made a link class to manage each object, this class is the linkedlist (manager) of the object private 
    public ReturnObjectImpl ro;
    int count;
    SampleableListImpl emptyList;
    SampleableListImpl nonEmptyList;

    public ReturnObject add(Object item) { 
        if (firstLink == null){
            firstLink = item;
            size++;
            firstLink.setIndex(0);
        System.out.println("Added linkedlink at 0");
        } else if (firstLink != null){
            Object current = firstLink; 
            while (current.getNextNode() != null){ //LOOPS HERE AFTER sample() sends the last object to be added to nonEmptyList
                current = current.getNextNode();
            } 
            current.setNextNode(item);
            size++;
            current.getNextNode().setIndex(size - 1);
            System.out.println("Added a new link to the existing linkedlist at " + current.getNextNode().getIndex());   
        }
        return null;
    }

    public SampleableList sample() { 
        if (firstLink == null){
            System.out.println("List is empty, so returning an empty sampableList");
            return emptyList = new SampleableListImpl();
        }
        Object current = firstLink;
        if (firstLink.getNextNode().getNextNode() != null){
            nonEmptyList = new SampleableListImpl();
            System.out.println("Adding to firstNode in nonEmptyList");
            nonEmptyList.add(firstLink);
            while (current.getNextNode().getNextNode() != null){
                current = current.getNextNode().getNextNode();
                System.out.println("Adding " + current.getIndex() + " to nonEmptyList");
                nonEmptyList.add(current);
            }
        } else {
                nonEmptyList.firstLink = current;
                System.out.println("There is only a head - no other objects to sample");
            }
        System.out.println("returning nonEmptyList");
        return nonEmptyList;
    }

}
```

And I am running this

```
SampleableListImpl sampList = new SampleableListImpl();
        Object ob = new Object();
        Object ob1 = new Object();
        Object ob2 = new Object();
        Object ob3 = new Object();
        Object ob4 = new Object();
        sampList.add(ob);
        sampList.add(ob1);
        sampList.add(ob2);
        sampList.add(ob3);
        sampList.add(ob4);
        sampList.sample();
```

Comment: Not sure but the double look aheads `link.getNextNode().getNextNode()` are smelly.

Comment: I should explain that sample returns the first, third, fifth... object in the list.

Comment: You must be tying it up into a circle somewhere, that's the only way that loop is going to do that. So what do you mean you can't change the methods or returns? The only thing that is left is the usage. So show the usage.

Answer (score 0):

When all 5 objects are added just before call `sample()`:

- `ob.getNextNode()` will return `ob1`.
- `ob1.getNextNode()` will return `ob2`.
- `ob2.getNextNode()` will return `ob3`.
- `ob3.getNextNode()` will return `ob4`.
- `ob4.getNextNode()` will return `null`.

`sample()` will in the first loop add `ob` again:

- `ob.getNextNode()` will return `ob1`.
- `ob1.getNextNode()` will return `ob2`.
- `ob2.getNextNode()` will return `ob3`.
- `ob3.getNextNode()` will return `ob4`.
- `ob4.getNextNode()` will return `ob`.

In the second loop within `sample()` it will try to add `ob2`, but it can no longer reach the end of your list.

What you could do to get around this, is create a copy of each object you want to add from `sample()` (and set their next node to `null` before adding).

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to do this with current, but it isn't working. Could you possibly suggest a way I might copy each object?

Comment: Even though i'm pretty sure your `Object` is some custom class and not `java.lang.Object`, you should be able to use `Object.clone()` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--)

Comment: A better solution would be to not store the next node inside the objects, but create a storage class for your `SampleableList` which can store an `Object` and a next node. That would avoid copies (of potentially big objects), and the list returned by `sample()` would have the same `ob`, `ob2` and `ob4` objects you initially put in.

Comment: Hmm seems I can't use that as I am not allowed to use exceptions or try/catch for this